# RSpec NoMethodError in broken mock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mocking

In `ApplicationController` I've got method which results I want to test in a `maintenance_mode_controller_specs`. How to create mock `maintenance_mode_active` method which will return false in specs?

`ApplicationController.rb`

```
def maintenance_mode_active
  # ...

  feature_flag.active
end
```

`maintenance_mode_controller_spec`

```
context 'when maintenance mode is inactive' do
  let(:application_controller) { instance_double(ApplicationController) }

  before do
    allow(ApplicationController).to receive(:new).and_return(application_controller)
    allow(application_controller).to receive(:maintenance_mode_active).and_return(false)
  end

  it 'redirect to root page' do
    get :maintenance_mode
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:redirect)
  end
end
```

with specs above I've got an error:

> Failure/Error: feature_flag.active
>
> NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `active' for nil:NilClass
>          Did you mean?  acts_like?

Which means mock doesn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use [`allow_any_instance_of`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance):

```
allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:maintenance_mode_active).and_return(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the stub is happening in the maintenance mode controller itself, you should try:

```
controller.stub(:maintenance_mode_active).and_return(false)
```

`allow_any_instance_of` or `expect_any_instance_of` is considered an anti-pattern for a number of reasons. You can read more about this [here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance)